# How to organize a C program that needs to create a Window and exit?

Tags: c, cron, ipc, xlib, code-organization

I am creating a c program that is called periodically. But upon meeting some conditions it might call a functions that uses X11 to create a window. That window will listen to events hence have a loop that waits for the events. So my C program has to wait till the created window finished doing its job. How do I make my program to call the function[defined in another c file] that creates the window and exit?

UPDATE: I was thinking of creating a socket between my C cron job and the server that handle creating the window and does what is instructed by the user. A good idea?

Answer (score 0):

`cron` doesn't normally have access to either a terminal or your X display. If you want it to, you'll have to figure out all the bits necessary for it to work (starting with setting `DISPLAY`, but possibly needing to delve into `xauth` and other things, and deciding what needs to be done when the display is not running, or locked, or running a different user, or ...) and incorporate all that in a script that then calls your program.

Comment: What do you mean by "cron doesn't access.."? What I'm planning to is to write a program that runs on specific interval( e.g. every minute). That program needs to call another routine that'll get into loop and exit. Tell me if I'm missing anything.